# How to configure and install psycogpg2 - beginner?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geodjango, psycopg2

I need to install psycogpg2 for working with 'django'.

I read the instructions but I don't understand whether to run the commands in command prompt or in Python command line. I am not used to the GUI installation.

So can you please anyone tell me how to configure settings and installation of psycogpg3 - where to keep the folders and changing directory etc. etc..

Answer (score 2):

you can download current stable Psycopg 2.4.6 [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/tarballs/psycopg2-latest.tar.gz) or you can use PyPI(Python Package Install) with `easy_install psycopg2`.

if you download package, you can install it with `python setup.py install` command. dont forget that you will probably need python-dev and libpq-dev packages.

> The pg_config must be available in your path, or alternatively you
>   must specify its full path in the setup.cfg file.

after installation, you can call it:

```
import psycopg2
```

and example code from [Postgresql Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial):

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost'
                            password='dbpass'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT datname from pg_database""")
rows = cur.fetchall()

print "\nShow me the databases:\n"
for row in rows:
    print "   ", row[0]
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks but where shall I run all these commands...as I said I am new to this kind of installation.

Comment: use terminal for installation. then write `python` to console for calling python then run this command. and it will help you to read this doc [How To: Python Programming Under Ubuntu](http://onecore.net/how-topython-programming-under-ubuntu.htm)